# What is the largest known zero-point energy for a molecule?

Tags: physical-chemistry, energy, theoretical-chemistry

I was surprised to find out that the zero-point energy (ZPE) for the ground state of $\ce{BH3}$ is a few thousand $\pu{cm-1}$, because for molecules I usually work with, it's much smaller. Does anyone know the largest recorded ZPE?

I have recently asked a similar question: [What is the biggest known difference between $r_e$ and $r_0$?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119548)

Comment: Liquid helium, maybe?

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Why liquid helium?

Comment: My understanding is this is what keeps it liquid to absolute zero unless compressed.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: I see. When I wrote "molecule" in the title, I didn't have a condensed phase material (like a liquid) in mind. I suppose I just had gas phase molecules in a vacuum, in mind.

Comment: Is the question about *vibrational* zpe? see eg https://www.nist.gov/sites/default/files/documents/srd/jpcrd362007389p.pdf

Comment: @buck of interest in your reference: Mg2 (which may form a weak bond if s-p mixing occurs in its MOs), NaLi (which may be considered a lithide).

Comment: I think this question has a trivial answer as written because the ZPE grows with the system size. A potentially more interesting question, and probably the spirit of the question, is what is the largest known zero point energy per atom? I think this may also somewhat trivially be H2 though... This is all assuming OP means vibrational ZPE which aligns with the example about BH3 I believe.

Comment: @jheindel: Perhaps H2 has the highest ZPE for a neutral diatomic in its ground electronic state. Yes I meant vibrational ZPE (the energy between v=0 and the minimum of the potential). We would guess this because H2 is light, so the levels are far apart. However the *shape* of the potential also matters right? He$_2$ has only one v-level and its outer turning point is all the way out at 20 Angstroms right? So could He2 have a bigger ZPE?

Comment: So, two things. Generally the ZPE in the v=0 level will be largest on the ground electronic state as higher electronically excited states tend to have larger anharmonicity. Also, the vibrational ZPE of a diatomic is greatly affected by the masses of the atoms involved, so H2 certainly has a higher ZPE than He2. Also H2 is much more strongly bound, so it will have a larger force constant. But as I said, the ZPE can be arbitrarily large, so I'm not sure exactly what you're interested in knowing about.